Make window only as large as required
In WinUI 3, how can I make the window only as large as required? Note that it should adapt its size in case the content gets larger while the application is running.
(negative) example:
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Window
    x:Class="SampleApp.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:local="using:SampleApp"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    mc:Ignorable="d">

    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center">
        <Button x:Name="myButton" Click="myButton_Click">Click Me</Button>
    </StackPanel>
</Window>

gets this window size, note how the window is much larger than the content (the button):


Subclass the main window and handle the WM_GETMINMAXINFO message according to your needs.

according to this discussion:
https://github.com/microsoft/microsoft-ui-xaml/discussions/9404
Add a SizeChanged event handler to your Window's root element. The event handler should look roughly like this:
private void OnRootSizeChanged(object sender, SizeChangedEventArgs e)
{
    var elm = (FrameworkElement)sender;
    elm.SizeChanged -= OnRootSizeChanged;

    var height = (int)Math.Ceiling(elm.DesiredSize.Height);
    var width = (int)Math.Ceiling(elm.DesiredSize.Width);

    AppWindow.ResizeClient(new(width, height));
    Activate();
}

